# List comprehension with multiple expressions and multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Before this wode was written that iterates over a file (ipaddress) using nested loops and a module (ipaddress). Now i would like to optimize using list comprehension.

```
import ipaddress
tmp1=open('Path\\Test-ip.txt', 'r+')
tmp2=open('Path\\-ip.txt', 'w+')
tmp1=tmp1.readlines()

for i in tmp1:
    i="".join(i.split())
     i=ipaddress.ip_network(i,False)
     for j in tmp1:
         j="".join(j.split())
         j=ipaddress.ip_network(j,False)
         if j != i:
             if ipaddress.IPv4Network(j).supernet_of(i):
                tmp2.write(str(i))
                tmp2.write('\n')
```

#Using List Comprehension

```
tmp1=open('Path\\Test-ip.txt', 'r+')
tmp2=open('Path\\Result-ip.txt', 'w+')
tmp1=tmp1.readlines()
tmp3=[ (("").join(i.split())) (("").join(j.split())) (ipaddress.ip_network(i)) (ipaddress.ip_network(j)) (tmp2.(write(str(i)))) for i in tmp1 for j in tmp1 if i!=j if ipaddress.IPv4Network(j).supernet_of(i)]
```

Comment: a) Why do you think a list comprehension is an optimisation? b) How can we help if we don't know what the original code was?

Comment: a) I need speed up my code and then from tutorial i read that using list-coprehension i can optimize and speedup my code b) I added original code.

Comment: List comprehension makes the code more concise but does not usually speed up the code by much, if any at all.

Comment: There *are* optimisations that can be made here, but not by making a list comprehension. For example, you're iterating through everything in the list for each element (O(N^2)) but I think you can just iterate once, and build up the list of things to write as you go. Could you explain what you actually want to happen?

Comment: There is a file that stores ip addresses, networks with a mask. For example (192.168.1.55,192.168.1.101, 192.168.1.56/24, 192.168.1.100/23) since the first three ip addresses are part of the 192.168.1.100/23 network. It should output (192.168.1.55,192.168.1.101, 192.168.1.56/24,) except "192.168.1.100/23". And there are a million such ip addresses in the file. It is required to quickly process and save in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

While *generally* a comprehension is faster than a `for`-loop, that is valid only if you are not doing things that are slow in the loop.

And (again *in general*) file I/O is *much slower* than doing calculations.

Note that you should *always* **measure** before trying to optimize. The bottleneck might not be where you think it is.

Run your script with `python -m cProfile -s tottime yourscript.py your arguments` and observe the output. That will tell you where the program is spending its time.
On my website, I have a list of articles detailing profiling of real-world python programs. You can find the first in the list [here](https://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/programming/profiling-python-scripts-1-stl2pov.html). The others are referenced at the bottom of that page.

If file I/O turns out to be the bottleneck, using memory mapped files (the `memmap` module) will probably improve things.